# Three.js Crosswalk Cordova blurry objects

Tags: android, cordova, three.js

I have a VR application that is looking really blurry in an app using Cordova & Crosswalk, but looks fine using the same code in Chrome in the browser. The device is an Android 4.4 device so I assume this is something to do with it, but hopefully there is a work around!

Here is an image showing it in the browser
[image]

And here it is in Cordova

Is there any solution anyone has seen to blurry fonts and images in Cordova and Crosswalk in WebGL on Android?

EDIT

It's the distance from camera, i.e when you zoom in it goes sharp. Any idea how to keep objects sharp at distance?

[image]

Comment: Try `crosswalk` plugin ?

Comment: yeah I'm using Crosswalk

Answer (score 0):

I increased the object size and used a power of 2 to size the components in canvas. This is better.